# How does Harper Lee's To Kill a Mockingbird represent the notion of self-conflict?

Tags: harper-lee, to-kill-a-mockingbird, psychoanalysis

I hope to get an answer, if I want to write about this topic. How does Harper Lee's *To Kill a Mockingbird* represent the notion of self-conflict? I am looking for an answer based on psychoanalytic criticism.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. This site is a bit different from a forum, so question like "what is the best x?" don't work very well here. What I recommend you to do is the following: (1) narrow the current question down to something like "How does Harper Lee's *To Kill a Mockingbird* represent the notion of self-conflict from a psychoanalytic point of view?" (2) post the question about Thomas Hardy's novel as a [separate question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). This increases your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Also, if this is a homework assignment you have been given, please do the research yourself.

Comment: @DJClayworth We don't downvote or close questions because they are homework. See [our policy on homework questions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/560/2191).